# jquery ajax post to express server get undefined data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express

im trying to get a form to submit some data to my express app.js without the page reloading. I thought i had the correct code but when it comes to getting the code from the ajax call to the server i get a undefined data variable.

app.js: (removed irrelevant lines)

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/web_text.json',function(req, res, next){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/web_text.json');
});

app.post('/sendEmail', function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body.data);

});

app.use('/', index);

module.exports = app;
```

jquery function that makes ajax call:

```
$('#reserve form').on('submit', function(){

    event.preventDefault();
    var data = {

        name: $('#name').val()
    };
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/sendEmail',
        data: data,
        method: 'POST'
    }).then(function (response) {
      // Do stuff with the response, like add it to the page dynamically.
      $('body').append(response);
    }).catch(function (err){

        console.error(err);
    });
});
```

note the console.log()s in my /sendEmail app.post function and the one in the jquery function. the jquery one logs the correct data while the app.post one logs a undefined variable... what am i doing wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: isnt it  console.log(res.body.data) instead of  console.log(req.body.data);

Comment: nope... made it worse, req.body.data resulted in a undefined data variable while the res.body.data resulted in a 500 error code right away

Comment: what does console.log(req.body) show?

Comment: alexander that did the trick! but why is it that i only need to use req.body instead of req.body.data? thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery is not POSTing JSON, it is sending a JS object. I would be willing to bet this is a content type issue. 
You might also want to look into `$('#reserve-form').serialize()` to package up your form data for sending instead of trying to manually create your object.

Answer (score 0):

in your app.js you didn't send the response. That is why you get undefined output. try this

```
app.post('/sendEmail', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.data);
    res.jsonp({data: 'your data'});
});
```

Hope this will help you.